# Transfer and manage domains to/within Azure?

Tags: azure, dns

I bought some domains a few years ago and managed it within the admin section the provider offered. I would like to manage both the domains and servers within one service, hence Azure. Is their a way to transfer my domain to a service within Azure? I know you can buy domains within Azure, hence I assume you can transfer them to Azure as well, though I read everywhere that I can only point them within the DNS.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure DNS (warning: currently in preview so no SLA)
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/dns/

You maintain the old registrar for all administrative activities (i.e. annually payment for your domain) and move technical activities on Azure (name server and DNS records). You can do that for all your domanin (yourdomain.com) or only for a zone (subdom.yourdomain.com).

Details here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-getstarted-create-dnszone-portal/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-domain-delegation/

Comment: Hence, it's not possible to transfer the registrars? But it is possible to buy domains within Azure? So, if I really want to move them, I can expire my domains and buy them through Azure? Or just accept that the administration will still be within my current provider. Right?

Comment: AFAIK, no.  From the last link "Keep in mind Azure DNS is not the domain registrar."